# Is there any easy way to 'Sign in With Google Play Games' in Flutter with Firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-play-games

Earlier, I did that with Google Sign in which didn't make it appeared in Google Play Games, games list and also I want to maintain global high scores, achievements with the help of Play Games. I only try it in Android App first and then iOS too with Game Center. But for now, just want to Sign in with Google Play Games.

Comment: Did you try this already?
https://pub.dev/packages/game_services_firebase_auth

Answer (score -1):

This tutorial seems to explain pretty well how to sign in with Google Play Games and integrate Game Center to use leaderboards and achievements : https://itnext.io/how-to-integrate-gamekit-and-google-play-services-flutter-4d3f4a4a2f77

Comment: You haven't read my question. It says with "FirebaseAuth" Service. Firebase auth offer the method of playGames signin in flutter but I don't know the procedure or anything.